# After replacing belt, LA125 blades are always engaged

Tags: lawn-mower

The belt that drives the mower blades bit the dust tonight and I replaced it with a spare.  It's actually the belt that came with the LA125 when it was purchased.  The problem is that there's too much tension on the belt and when the engine is on, the belt is engaged, driving the blades.  I've backed off on the belt tensioner as far as I can, and even went as far as removing one of the bolts that hold the tensioner in place so I could move it further.

If the deck is lowered considerably, between 1-2 inches, the belt is relaxed and the blades will not turn...if it's raised above 3, too much tension is on it and the blades engage.

The tensioner pulley is all the way to the right (looking down at the deck) so I don't think it's being pulled by the cable.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here, but the first things that come to mind  are making sure the path is correct, that it is seated correctly, and that there are no twists in the belt. I don't know the mechanism, but if it were on "inside-out" it might not seat as deep as it should into the groove and then that would make it tighter than it should be. These problems may not even be possible with this mechanism, but it's all I've got.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the belt on right...I was careful to follow the existing belt before I took it off.  It's possible that I have flipped inside out...I'll have to check that.  How much of a difference do think that'll make?

Comment: Again, this is pure speculation, but I wouldn't be surprised if putting it on like inside out, if possible, would change how it sits by 1/4 to 1/2"

Comment: You were right; that was the issue.

Comment: Wow, Idiot!!  That was pretty incredible!!  DIY stuff should be attempted only after you've talked with experts.  I made friends with 2-stroke engine tool-fixers!  Take your mowers, weedwackers, blowers in to a great company and when they fix or go through these tools, they'd love to educate...otherwise, ask IDIOT, grins!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first things that come to mind are making sure the path is correct, that it is seated correctly, and that there are no twists in the belt. I don't know the mechanism, but if it were on "inside-out" it might not seat as deep as it should into the groove and then that would make it tighter than it should be. I wouldn't be surprised if putting it on inside out would change how it sits making it tighter by 1/4 to 1/2"