# Husqvarna R322T AWD blades engage with deck up after replacing middle belt

Tags: lawn-mower

I had to replace the middle belt. I have the correct belt, have it on correctly but now the blades engage with the deck up. What would cause this?

Comment: If you replaced the belt yourself, the thing that comes immediately to mind is what I answered another question about a mower blade that was always engaged after a belt change - the belt might be inside-out: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20375/after-replacing-belt-la125-blades-are-always-engaged

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that mower, but I assume the sensor on the back to detect if the deck up is maybe in the wrong position (maybe just by moving/tilling the mower). Try to move it up down (on inside, out). And check again.

Eventually you should check the wire which connect it. Maybe now it do a longer "travel" (maybe installing the belt, you moved it). Ev. check and adjust the cable length (check on both side, there should be a mechanism. Note: the true cable could be hidden on a protective tube.

It is in any case difficult to diagnose and explain what to do, from an internet site (and from a person who do no know your model). Try to touch and move different cables (not too strong, only the cables that go toward the back/bottom, not cables on motor/batteries/etc.), to see if they were blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The new belt is to tight therefore the brake will not hold the blades when the deck is up